# let statement inside an ocaml for loop

Tags: for-loop, ocaml

I am a ocaml noob so apologies for the stupid question. My google skills have failed me!

I am trying to do a series of let bindings and want to do them in a for loop (I know, I know). When I put a let binding in the for loop the "done;;" becomes a syntax error. I assume I'm missing something obvious. Any other pointers for the following MWE are welcome:

```
module PF = Map.Make(struct type t = int let compare = compare end);;
module Factorize = Map.Make(struct type t = int let compare = compare end);;

let a = PF.empty;;
let a = PF.add 2 5 a;;
let a = PF.add 3 3 a;;
let b = PF.empty;;
let b = PF.add 3 1 b;;
let b = PF.add 5 2 b;;

let print_map = PF.iter (fun a b -> Printf.printf "%d %d\n" a b);;

print_map a;;
print_map b;;

(*THESE LET BINDINGS WORK*)
let primeFactors = Factorize.empty;;
let primeFactors = Factorize.add 1 (PF.add 1 3 PF.empty) primeFactors;;
let primeFactors = Factorize.add 2 (PF.add 2 3 PF.empty) primeFactors;;
let primeFactors = Factorize.add 3 (PF.add 3 3 PF.empty) primeFactors;;

(*BUT WE CANNOT DO A BUNCH OF THEM IN A LOOP*)
for k = 4 to 20 do
  let primeFactors = Factorize.add k (PF.add k 3 PF.empty) primeFactors;
done;;  (* THIS LINE FAILS*)
```

It's not strictly a MWE, but the idea is that there are two mappings. The first maps int to int and the second maps int to a PF mapping.

The let binding itself seems to work. But somehow having a let binding causes the done to fail. My guess is that it is supposed to be returning a (), but I couldn't figure out how to make it do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be a bit confusing at first. The `let` keyword functions differently at the top level then it does in the context of an expression.

The first group of `let` bindings are at the top-level of your module. The syntax for top level bindings is `let x = expr`. This is what you have in the let bindings preceding the `for` loop (the trailing `;;` aren't needed unless you're working in the interactive top-level, but they won't hurt anything).

However, in any other context (e.g., in your `for` loop), `let` bindings  bind a variable `in` a local scope. The syntax for this is `let x = expr1 in expr2` -- note the `in`. The `in` separates the binding of the variable (here `x` to the value `expr1`) from the following scope in which this binding holds (here `expr2`).

E.g.,

```ml
for k = 4 to 20 do
  let v = k * k in
  print_endline (string_of_int v)
done
```

Note that, when doing imperative programming with `ref` cells, you don't need let bindings to update the values of the `ref` cell:

```ml
let v = ref 0 in
  for k = 4 to 20 do
    v := !v + k
  done;
  print_endline (string_of_int !v);
(* => 204 *)
```

Please let me know if this seems unclear or you have any followup questions!

Comment: Thank you. In [this mapping tutorial](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/map.html) they used the let binding. I had the "ref" in my code by mistake because I was trying other things while debugging. But how would I do a sequence of let bindings in a for loop? Ie I was the primeFactors mapping to have all the mappings in it from the sequence.  Making it a reference did not seem to do the trick as the primeFactors mapping just had units in it.

Comment: Actually, using a ref works perfectly. That's probably the right way to do it. I sort of understand why the let binding didn't work in the loop but not really. But thanks!

Comment: Happy to help!  You may want to skim through the section on "variables and functions" in Real World Ocaml: https://dev.realworldocaml.org/variables-and-functions.html  It should help clarify the syntax for `let` bindings.

Comment: I've made some edits to my answer based on your feedback. Please let me know if this helps clarify the issue. :)

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR; `let` is not an assignment `:=`. Let creates a lexical binding, it doesn't change any values.

First of all, you're confusing assignment with shadowing.

When you do

```
let x = 42
let x = 52
```

You're not changing the value of `x`, you bind the variable `x` to the new value `52`. In OCaml, variables are purely mathematical, in a sense that they do not act as a storage cell and do not store anything inside themselves. They are just names, which are used by a programmer to refer to a result of an expression.

Moreover, you can even bind values of different types to the same identifier, e.g.,

```
let x = 42
let x = "hello"
```

Now, to create a reference cell, which as an object where you can store a value, you can use the `ref` function. It will return a box with a place ready to store 
your values.

```
let x = ref 42
```

and to change the value stored in this cell you have to use the `(:=)` function, e.g.,

```
 x := 56
```

Now, the value stored in the cell which we reference by the name `x` is `56`, and to retrieve this value, you have to use the `(!)` function. For example, the following will double the value stored in the cell:

```
x := !x * !x
```

And you can do this in a cycle,

```
for i = 0 to 9 do
    x := !x * !x
done
```

---

Now, let's look on what did you do :)

```
let primeFactors = ref Factorize.empty;;
```

You create a cell that contains an empty map and bound it to the `primeFactors` name. The value bound to the `primeFactors` variable has type `Factorize.t ref`, i.e., a reference to `Factorize.t`. So far so good!

```
let primeFactors = Factorize.add 1 (PF.add 1 3 PF.empty) primeFactors;;
```

First of all, it won't compile, since `Factorize.add` expects `Factorize.t` but you're giving it a value of type `Factorize.t ref`. Though, it is syntactically correct, it is not a valid program. However, even if we will make it well-typed, by dereferencing the cell to its value via the `(!)` function

```
let primeFactors = Factorize.add 1 (PF.add 1 3 PF.empty) !primeFactors
```

It will be still a wrong program (not all programs that are well-typed are correct!).
What we did here, we rebound the `primeFactors` variable to a new value which is a  map from `1` to `(PF.add 1 3 PF.empty)` value. So we changed the value associated with the `primeFactors` variable, as well as its type. What we should do, is

```
primeFactors := Factorize.add 1 (PF.add 1 3 PF.empty) !primeFactors
```